# Last dropdown not working base on previous dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have a list of dropdowns that are base off the previous one. They pull their data based on the selection of the previous selection and populate the next dropdown.  I am using the same code, but for some reason, it is not working on the last one.  Here is the JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready( function() { 
    $("#order").change(function() {
        $(this).after('<div id="loader"><img src="img/ajax-loader.gif" alt="loading subcategory" /></div>');
        $.get('loadFamilies.php?order=' + $(this).val(), function(data) {
            $("#family").html(data);
            $('#loader').slideUp(200, function() {
                $(this).remove();
            });
        }); 
    }); 

    $("#family").change(function() {
        $(this).after('<div id="loader"><img src="img/ajax-loader.gif" alt="loading subcategory" /></div>');
        $.get('loadSubFamilies.php?family=' + $(this).val(), function(data) {
            $("#subfamily").html(data);
            $('#loader').slideUp(200, function() {
                $(this).remove();
            });
        }); 
    }); 

    $("#subfamily").change(function() {
        $(this).after('<div id="loader"><img src="img/ajax-loader.gif" alt="loading subcategory" /></div>');
        $.get('loadGenus.php?subfamily=' + $(this).val(), function(data) {
            $("#genus").html(data);
            $('#loader').slideUp(200, function() {
                $(this).remove();
            });
        }); 
    }); 

    $("#genus").change(function() {
        $(this).after('<div id="loader"><img src="img/ajax-loader.gif" alt="loading subcategory" /></div>');
        $.get('loadSpecies.php?genus=' + $(this).val(), function(data) {
            $("#species").html(data);
            $('#loader').slideUp(200, function() {
                $(this).remove();
            });
        }); 
    }); 
});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<form method="get">
    <label for="order">Order</label>
    <select name="order" id="order">
        <option value="0">Select an Order</option>
        <?php 
            $orders = get_ID_and_name_of_orders();
            foreach($orders as $key => $value) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $value; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
    <br/><br/>

    <label>Family</label>
    <select name="family" id="family"></select><br/><br/>
    <label>Sub Family</label>
    <select name="subfamily" id="subfamily"></select><br/><br/>
    <label>Genus</label>
    <select name="genus" id="genus"></select><br/><br/>
    <label>Species</label>
    <select name="species" id="species"></select><br/><br/>
</form>
```

Here is loadGenus.php for getting the genus:

```
$subfamily = $_GET['subfamily'];
$genus = get_genus($subfamily); // from database
echo("<option value='0'>Select a Genus (optional)</option>");
foreach($genus as $key => $value) {
    echo("<option value='$key'>$value</option>");
}
```

Here is loadSpecies.php for getting the speicies:

```
$genus = $_GET['genus'];
$species = get_species($genus);
echo("<option value='0'>Select a Species (optional)</option>");
foreach($species as $key => $value) {
    echo("<option value='$key'>$value</option>");
}
```

All of the dynamic dropdowns work except for the species one.  I have looked at this for hours and debugged everything I can and cannot see why the options are not being populated in the species dropdown.  I have isolated the call to loadSpecies.php and it returns with the correct list of species options by itself. The JavaScript runs with no errors.  No errors in the console.

I am hoping another set of eyes might see something I am missing here. Thank you in advance!

code for get_Species:
    function get_species($genus_id) {
    global $database;
    $sql = $database->query("SELECT id, species_name FROM species where genus_id = ".$database->escape_value($genus_id)." ORDER BY species_name");
    $speciesArray = array();
    while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
        $speciesArray[$row['id']] = $row['species_name'];
    }
    return $speciesArray;
}

Comment: Sounds like a cool project

Comment: there's no SQL queries here I assume your using the function get_species() can we see this function?

Comment: ok, added code for get_species

Comment: I can't see a fault with that I might have a look later got to go to work!

Answer (score 0):

User error! I had an require statement in my php that was including other HTML that had a an element with an id of species--an ambiguous id reference. I changed the id to another name and it worked.